# ImportError: cannot import name BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python

I try to run first example from [python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer) and when I try to run it:

```
$ python BaseHttpServer.py
```

I get an error **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BaseHTTPRequestHandler'**.

I tested it on Python 2.7.3 on Linux Mageia 2 64-bit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BaseHTTPServer.py", line 9, in <module>
    import BaseHTTPServer
  File "/home/vanveber/BaseHttpServer/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 14, in <module>
    class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BaseHTTPRequestHandler'
```

And it on Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7 64-bit

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BaseHTTPServer.py", line 11, in <module>
    from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\BaseHttpServer\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 11, in <module>
    from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
ImportError: cannot import name BaseHTTPRequestHandler
```

**BUT!**

1. BaseHttpServer is a class from **standard Python library**.
2. If I write and run this code from **Python GUI on Windows** it works correctly!

What is a problem and why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution: Rename the python file.**

**Explanation:** BaseHTTPServer is a module in the standard library. When you have a python file called BaseHTTPServer.py in your local directory, you will hide the standard library module, and you can no longer import it, because the statement

```
import BaseHTTPServer
```

will not import the standard library module, but the local BaseHTTPServer.py module.